# Getting section headins in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

In my ms word document , I insert various heading throughout my document and then make a TOC from it. I'd like for headings to be automatically number so I see:

```
1 My Heading
1.1 My Sub heading
1.1.1 My sub subheading
```

How do I configure word to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It matters what version are you using. Please [edit] your question so we can give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word 2010 it is on the Home Ribbon as MultiLevel List. What you described is a preformated option to choose from.

[image]